# Giving the user the choice between open a picture in colors or black and white in c++

Tags: c++

My problem is when I input N or Y it will open the picture in black and white, can someone please help me figure this out.

```
int main()

{

cout << "Do you want the picture to be in greyscale (Y/N)";

    int Y;  
    int N;  

    cin >> Y; 
    cin >> N; 

    Mat GRAY;
    Mat A;

    GRAY = imread("Maelk.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);    // The picture in gray
    A = imread("Maelk.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);   // Picture in colors    

    char answer = 0;
    switch (answer);
    cin >> answer;

    if(answer == 'N')

{   
    namedWindow("Milk");

    imshow("Milk", A); 
}

else

    namedWindow("Milk");

    imshow("Milk", GRAY);

    waitKey (0);

}
```

Comment: You `else` lacks brackets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have opening `else` braces.

```
else
{ //add this opening brace
    namedWindow("Milk");
```

Also, you do not need a `switch` in your code.

```
switch (answer); //does not do anything
```

The variables `Y` and `N` are also useless. Since you are reading the user response in `answer`, they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the braces around your `else` statement:

```
else
{

    namedWindow("Milk");

    imshow("Milk", GRAY);
}
```

If you don't have these, the the `imshow` line gets executed every time, possibly overwiting the colour image with the greyscale one.